# CompletableFuture handle and completeExceptionally cannot work together?

Tags: java, exception, completable-future

I am trying to set a **default** value when exceptions happen in `CompletableFuture` I made it work by `handle` method as follows:

```
private static void testHandle() {
    String name = null;
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }).handle((s, t) -> s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!" + t.toString());
    out.println(completableFuture.join());
}
```

But when I tried to stop the `CompletableFuture` using `completeExceptionally` when bad things happen and track the *exception* as follows I cannot catch **the exception** as I did just now.

```
private static void testCompleteExceptionally() {
    String name = "Hearen";
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        delay(500L);
        if (name == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }).handle((s, t) -> {
        try {
            throw t.getCause(); 
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            out.println(e.toString()); // I was hoping to record the custom exceptions here;
        }
        return s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!" + t.toString();
    });

    if (name != null) {
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Calculation failed!")); // when bad things happen, I try to complete it by exception;
    }
    out.println(completableFuture.join());

}
```

**UPDATED** 2018-06-09 Thanks for the help, @Daniele

```
private static void testCompleteExceptionally() {
    String name = "Hearen";
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        delay(500L);
        if (name == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    });

    if (name != null) {
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Calculation failed!"));
    }
    out.println(completableFuture.handle((s, t) ->  s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!" + t.toString()).join());

}
```

The **handle** enclosed just before `join()` works as expected. But in this case, the `returned value` will be `null`.

Based on the [handle API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

> Returns a **new** CompletionStage that, when this stage completes either normally or exceptionally, is executed with this stage's result and exception as arguments to the supplied function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a `future`, piping with an `handle` (so getting another future) and then completing exceptionally the future returned by the `handle`.

You should complete exceptionally the inner `future` itself, instead of the `handle`.

The point here is that `handle` returns another future; and you should not complete the "outer" future exceptionally, because doing that will bypass the handling behavior.

Below the code;

```
package stackOv;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class TestHandle {
  BiFunction<String, Throwable, String> handle2 = new BiFunction<String, Throwable, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String s, Throwable t) {
      try {
        throw t.getCause(); 
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        // I was hoping to record the custom exceptions here;
        System.out.println(e.toString());
      }
      return s != null ? s : "Hello, Stranger!" + t.toString();
    }
  };

  private void testCompleteExceptionally() {
    String name = "Hearen";
    Supplier<String> supplier2 = () -> {
      delay(500L);
      if (name == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Computation error!");
      }
      return "Hello, " + name;
    };
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier2);

    if (name != null) {
      // when bad things happen, I try to complete it by exception;
      completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Calculation failed!"));      
    }
    System.out.println(completableFuture.handle(handle2).join());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestHandle th = new TestHandle();
    th.testCompleteExceptionally();
  }

  private static void delay(long milli) {
    try { Thread.sleep(milli); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}    
  }
}
```